# Browsing and selecting on 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have 2 DataFrames like this:

```
df1
     Id     B
3    alpha  1
18   alpha  3
125  alpha  5
230  alpha  9
```

where `3, 18, 125, 230` are the index of df1

and:

```
df2
     Id     B
1    Beta  21
2    Beta  33
5    Beta  120
7    Beta  36
10   Beta  32
14   Beta  71
15   Beta  210
21   Beta  53
123  Beta  22 
127  Beta  1227
128  Beta  11
227  Beta  7
235  Beta  18
```

**My question :** 
How can I browse my df2 to extract the rows coming before and after each row of my df1 based on the index?

My desired output :

```
df2
     Id     B
2    Beta  33
5    Beta  120
15   Beta  210
21   Beta  53
123  Beta  22 
127  Beta  1227
227  Beta  7
235  Beta  18
```

Comment: Can you post the ouput too?

Comment: @jat done! i edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) for positions, add one previous values,  join by [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) and select by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
a = df2.index.searchsorted(df1.index) 
df = df2.iloc[sorted(np.r_[a, a-1])]
print (df)
       Id     B
2    Beta    33
5    Beta   120
15   Beta   210
21   Beta    53
123  Beta    22
127  Beta  1227
227  Beta     7
235  Beta    18
```

Answer (score 1):

A more verbose way to accomplish this is get the location of the indexes from `df1` and plus-minus one to them.

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index()

li = []
for ind in df1.index:
    ind_loc = df.index.get_loc(ind)
    li.extend([ind_loc - 1, ind_loc + 1])

print(df.iloc[li])
```